# Qt reference QTabBar into speficic QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet

I've a QTabWidget with some tabs, and in the last tab i've a widget that contains another QTabWidget.
When I customize the `QTabBar::Tab` of the first QTabWidget, Qt also customize me the 2nd QTab bar in the other QTabWidget.

It's possible to identify it in the Stylesheet in a univoque mode?
I can specify `QTabWidget#myId1` and `QTabWidget#myId2`
But I can't separate the TabBar like `QTabBar#myId1` or `QTabWidget#myId1::QTabBar`

Any suggestion?

Comment: use objectName like #objectName { style sheet }

Comment: I need to specify the ‘QTabBar::tab’ property, I cannot use ‘QTabBar#myId::tab’